# MS-SQL 2008 Server : Wrong Syntax?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error

I having a problem with this command line:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.njams_test_sql_2.[PROC_DELETE_DATA]')
             AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [PROC_DELETE_DATA]
GO
```

Following SubSelect-Command:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID ( N'dbo.njams_test_sql_2.[PROC_DELETE_DATA]'
```

Gives the error that there is an syntax error in the near of

`'dbo.njams_test_sql_2.[PROC_DELETE_DATA]'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a bracket is missing at the end

Comment: You are missing the `)` bracket from second query.

Comment: Is your database really called `dbo`?

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005**, it is recommended to use the **most focused** system catalog views - e.g. use `SELECT * FROM sys.procedures ...` if you're interested in stored procedures (instead of `sys.objects`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bracket is missing at the end

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID ( N'dbo.njams_test_sql_2.[PROC_DELETE_DATA]' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query runs perfectly..
but you are missing ')' in your second query.

Use following query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.njams_test_sql_2.[PROC_DELETE_DATA]')
```